# unable to convert string to date c#

Tags: c#, datetime, c#-4.0

I'm trying to convert `string` formatted like `09172014` into `DateTime`

```
string mydate = "09172014";
DateTime newDate = DateTime.Parse(mydate);
```

but failed to do so. I know it must be easy trick but getting wierd errors :(`

Comment: You need to use the [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, if you want to use your own date format.

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this :

```
string myDate = "09172017"
DateTime newDate = DateTime.ParseExact(myDate, "MMddyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

then you can convert MMddyyyy date to DateTime.

Comment: As with a previous answer that was edited, this is badly formatted. I haven't seen the month '17' before ;). Plus I think you're getting a little ahead of the times with the year, too

Comment: @ashish This answer doesn't _even_ work. Why do you accept this?

Answer (score 3):

You should provide format.

```
string mydate = "09172014";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(mydate, "MMddyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use ParseExact:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("09172014", "MMddyyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dt=DateTime.ParseExact(mydate, "MMddyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try ParseExact:

```
  string dateString, format;  
  DateTime result;
  CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

  // Parse date and time with custom specifier.
  dateString = "09172014";
  format = "MMddyyyy";
  try {
     result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
     Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, result.ToString());
  }
  catch (FormatException) {
     Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateString);
  }
```

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: this can be shortened right down into something like the other answers.

Comment: Correct but you need to make sure that the string is in the correct format, I would use if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "MMddyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))